# Why isn't enabling on the fly projection reflected in raster? QGIS 1.8.0

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have imported a map from the Ordnance Survey Open Data website. It is a 50k Street View raster. I have also created a new shapefile layer in which I have created a polygon overlay for the raster map. I have enabled "On the fly projection" in the Settings menu and also selected OSGB1936 CRS for both layers. However, it is apparent from the co-ordinates displayed at the bottom of the map pane that this CRS is not activated.

What do I need to do to apply the desired CRS?

Comment: reproject them properly? What is your projects projection?

Answer (score 3):

If the OS data is in metres or kilometres, the CRS for that layer should be EPSG:27700.

Please note that **layer** CRS and **project** CRS are different things. If you want lat/lon degrees in the status bar display, the **project** CRS should be EPSG:4277 or EPSG:4326, but that gives you a distorted view. If you want the OS units, choose EPSG:27700 for the project as well.

Comment: Both layer AND project CRS are set at OSGB1936 with EPSG:27700. The coordinates shown at the bottom of the map pane are both 4 digits, with the y co-ord as a minus value. I have used OS rasters before (not Street view as in this case) and the x,y coordinates are always 6 figure grids that corroborate with hard copy maps.

Comment: Try going to settings and project settings. perhaps the layers are being reporjected in the project crs through on the fly. So just define your layer crs in project properties.